# python - how to use the join method and sort method

Tags: python, function, sorting, join

My purpose is to get an input as a string and return a list of lower case letters of that string, without repeats, without punctuations, in alphabetical order. For example, the input "happy!" would get ['a','h','p','y']. I try to use the join function to get rid of my punctuations but somehow it doesn't work. Does anybody know why? Also, can sort.() sort alphabets? Am I using it in the right way? Thanks!

```
def split(a):
    a.lower()
    return [char for char in a]

def f(a):
    i=split(a)
    s=set(i)
    l=list(s)
    v=l.join(u for u in l if u not in ("?", ".", ";", ":", "!"))
    v.sort()
    return v
```

Comment: is that your actual code? because there is an error on the line `l.join`, since l is a list type.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you mean by 'it doesn't work'.  For one thing, a.lower() doesn't modify the string ```a```.  You need to set ```a.lower()``` to some other variable and use that in your list comprehension in the next line.

Answer (score 4):

`.join()` is a string method, but being used on a list, so the code raises an exception, but `join` and isn't really needed here.

You're on the right track with `set()`. It only stores unique items, so create a set of your input and compute the intersection(&) with lower case letters.  Sort the result:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'Happy!'
>>> sorted(set(s.lower()) & set(string.ascii_lowercase))
['a', 'h', 'p', 'y']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
def f(a):
    return sorted(set(a.lower().strip('?.;:!')))
```

---

```
>>> f('Happy!')
['a', 'h', 'p', 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex for this:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'[^a-z]')

string = 'Hello@ W0rld!!#@'

print(sorted(set(pattern.sub('', string))))
```

Output:

```
['d', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r']
```

Comment: @MarkTolonen ah, my bad. just had a read htrough the question again, must have missed that.

Comment: @xinhwa my pleasure!